# Bootstrap navbar not expands although included all js and css source files

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am totally helpless don't know what the hell is wrong. I included all the js and css files got no error in developer console. Please help me out. Bootstrap navbar doesn't expands when i click no the Button.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Twitter Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <style type="text/css">
    .box{
            background-color:green;
            border:1px grey solid;
        }
    </style>    

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">My website</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>


                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="">Details</li></a>
                <li><a href="">About Us</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<h1>Hellow World!</h1>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hit F12, what errors do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data-toggle spelling mistake. U forgot to write - (hyphen) in between.

Comment: "hyphen", but yes, this is what he's missing. Good eye!

Comment: Thank u for my spell corrections. I feek like Alzheimer's

Comment: Something's wrong with me... I hate typing on mobile. Gn

Answer (score 2):

Check your tags:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="">Details</li></a>
  <li><a href="">About Us</li></a>
</ul>
```

Should be:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="">Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Bootply of Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/1LoGn9oHVW)

On other thing I can think of, make sure your `<head>` and `<body>` completes properly. They aren't present in my example, and it works, so maybe there's something wrong with that.

Comment: No it didn't expand i copy pasted the corrected code, checked twice. :( Did that code worked for you?

Comment: Check happy2deepak's answer, he's got it right. Make sure to check all attributes, check tags are in the write area, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code works as expected ? Look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/u2496yq2/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

fiddle above updated. Your problem is the datatoggle of your collapse button. You need to modify like this : data-toggle

Comment: It really doesn't though... Resize the window and press the expand button. Does the drop down appear?

Comment: Make sure you read the question completely and only post an answer if you've answered what they're asking. If you need clarification, leave a comment and go from there.